# Mouse tracking in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am implementing a code in which when I push the line button, I can track the points to get a line. But for again tracking a line a line I need to push the button again. I want until Esc key is pressed the same signal must remain activated. I don't want to push the button again and again. The code snippet is:
mainwindow.cpp

```
    connect(ui->lineButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(drawLine()));
void MainWindow::drawLine(){

    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    line *item = new line;
    scene->addItem(item);
    //connect(item,SIGNAL(drawFinished()),SLOT(drawLine()));

    qDebug() << "Line Created";


}
```

line.cpp

```
    void line::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* e){
       if(e->button()==Qt::LeftButton) {
           if(mFirstClick){
               x1 = e->pos().x();
               y1 = e->pos().y();
               mFirstClick = false;
               mSecondClick = true;
           }

           else if(!mFirstClick && mSecondClick){
               x2 = e->pos().x();
               y2 = e->pos().y();
               mPaintFlag = true;
               mSecondClick = false;
               update();

           }
       }
       QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(e);
       update();

   }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your need, would make it clear what your goal (what exactly the code should do), edit your question, please add in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: For some reason the `setMouseTracking (true);` requires that the mouse is pressed to capture the coordinates.

When the mouse is pressed, so it will not work all the time, you can create is a separate thread that runs all the time.

This "Thread" should be a boolean variable is variable to be `true` when the mouse is pressed. If Esc is pressed set `false` (When the window is inactive or lose focus, you could create another boolean variable to block the event and the window to regain focus event back to work).

Inside the "Thread", you create an infinite loop, something like:

```
class myCapture: QThread {
   bool capture;
   ...
}

while(1) {
   if(capture) {

   }
}
```

and using `QEvent`, should detect the position of the mouse.

Example for use:

trackmouse.h:

```
#ifndef TRACKMOUSE_H
#define TRACKMOUSE_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QPoint>

class trackMouse : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit trackMouse(QObject *parent = 0);
    void enable(const bool enable = true);
    void detectMove(const bool enable = true);
    void setDelay(const int value);
    void end();

protected:
    virtual void run();

private:
    int delay;
    bool track;
    bool running;
    bool lastPosActive;

signals:
    void mousePos(const QPoint pos);
};

#endif // TRACKMOUSE_H
```

trackmouse.cpp:

```
#include "trackmouse.h"
#include <QCursor>
#include <QDebug>

trackMouse::trackMouse(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent),
    delay(10),
    track(false),
    running(true),
    lastPosActive(false)
{
}

void trackMouse::end() {
    running = false;
    wait();
    terminate();
}

void trackMouse::enable(const bool enable) {
    track = enable;
}

void trackMouse::detectMove(const bool enable) {
    lastPosActive = enable;
}

void trackMouse::setDelay(const int value) {
    delay = value;
}

void trackMouse::run() {
    QPoint lastPos;
    QPoint currentPost;

    while(running) {
        QThread::msleep(delay);
        currentPost = QCursor::pos();
        if (track == true && (lastPosActive == false || lastPos != currentPost)) {
            lastPos = currentPost;
            emit mousePos(currentPost);
        }
    }
}
```

Configure mainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    tt = new trackMouse(this);
    //tt->setDelay(1000); // 1 second
    tt->detectMove(true); //If true, will only "Track" when the mouse moves.
    QObject::connect(tt, SIGNAL(mousePos(QPoint)), this, SLOT(capture(QPoint)));
    tt->start();
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "enable mouse track";
    tt->enable();//enable track on click
}

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape) {
        qDebug() << "disable mouse track";
        tt->enable(false);
    }
}

void MainWindow::capture(const QPoint pos){
    qDebug() << "X:" << pos.x() << " | Y: " << pos.y();
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    tt->end();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "trackmouse.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    trackMouse *tt;

private slots:
    void capture(const QPoint pos);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to proceed. Actually I am just a beginner in Qt. Can you provide little more? Do I need to separate class, then how to use it another one. Can you give me a small example?

Comment: I had no error, but line was made once only:( I had to again push the button the for tracking the points to draw the line. In the output window it showed me  like this: Line Created
enable mouse track
X: 459  | Y:  299
X: 453  | Y:  299
X: 436  | Y:  292

Comment: Compress your project and put the link in your question in order to download and test on my machine.

Comment: @user3569153 replace `void ellipse::mouseMoveEvent` by "trackmouse class", the code I used with QMainWindow only example. You should adapt it to your code. `capture(const QPoint pos)` (add in ellipse class) is "slot" you should use to work placement.

Comment: We have to create trackmouse.h and trackmouse.cpp. And in ellipse.cpp mousemove event is to be replaced with what? I didn't get. And I need to create a slot in .h file for all entities I guess. Am I right?

Comment: Please give me rough idea of what is happening in the code. Little theoretical idea. I am unable to understand it:(

Comment: Can you edit my code? So that I can have a clear view of what changes need to done and after that I can discuss the issues with you about what part I understood and what not. If it is comfortable to you. I want to learn this concept of threads. And I think you can really help me.

Comment: Please, try to understand my code without thinking in your code, try to understand after adjusting it to your needs.